White Fungus at the Base of a Norway Maple
Sorry for the late response. The 2nd image is a closeup of the fungus.
The image below shows a white fungus or mold at the a base of a Norway Maple tree. Due to nightly watering, the soil is damp. Currently the trunk, branches, and leaves of the tree are healthy. Can anyone identify this fungus? Can this fungus lead to trunk or root rot?


Do you have any closer-up pictures?
